# Sort Excel File Natural Order

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

How might I sort an excel file by [Natural Order](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39468/windows-explorer-natural-order) based on a column with either VBA or Mathematica?  [This question is similar](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/38891/formatting-excel-borders-with-net) although probably not as complex.

In addition how can I ignore a heading like so?

```
Heading
Ie4 01
Ie4!01
Ie4_01
Ie4_128
Ie5
Ie6
Ie401sp2
Ie501sp2
```

Comment: I am not aware that Excel or any other tool support the quite *unnatural* 'natural order' of Explorer. otherwise, sorting in Excel is straightforward, and treats header lines correctly automatically.

Comment: @Aganju That is exactly what I concluded  I chose natural order because it is something we use every day although any sort function should be able to be put in place of the previous one.  I was quit disappointed how many features are missing from excel, although excel is likely complex enough as is.

Comment: If you're asking what I think your are, you can create a helper column and use the SUBSTITUTE function to remove things like spaces, commas, hyphens, etc that you don't want Excel considering for sorting, and then sort on the helper column. I do this in a spreadsheet of all my DVD/Blu-rays so Excel won't sort on those and other items such as the word "The". I can post as an answer if this is what you're looking for.

Comment: @BillOer That sounds really useful but not exactly what I am looking for.  Do you have a write up somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

I have a formula I use in my DVD/Blu-ray spreadsheet that allows me to ignore certain characters and words when sorting. It uses the SUBSTITUTE function to remove the characters I don't want to be considered for sorting. The formula looks like this:

> =SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B2,"The ","",1),",","")," ",""),".",""),"&","and"),":",""),"'","")

It substitutes "The " with nothing, comma with nothing, space with nothing, period with nothing, ampersand with "and", colon with nothing, and quote sign with nothing.
(I also have another formula that I use for removing everything between the brackets I use in the titles to include short comments like "one of boxed set," but I didn't think anyone would be interested.)